# Compare date's date part only with Timestamp in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have timestamp in database and in application i do have date . I like to write hibernate criteria in the way that hibernate can pull all entries those matches with date, not time part.
e.g.

in DB timestamp

2011-12-01 15:14:14

and in application i do have java.util.Date which has by default time part.

my problem is when i search entries from database with following code i get nothing

```
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(MyClass.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.like(TIMESTAMP_FIELD, javaUtilDate));
    List entries =this.getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are looking for a **general use of filtering by date range** (eg. from today until tomorrow).
I use it that way:

YourService.java

```
Date fromTimestamp = new Date();
Date toTimestamp = new Date();
Date fromDate = DateHelper.getDateWithoutTime(fromTimestamp);
Date toDate = DateHelper.getDateWithoutTime(DateHelper.getTomorrowDate(toTimestamp));
```

YourDAO.java

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge(TIMESTAMP_FIELD, fromDate));
criteria.add(Restrictions.le(TIMESTAMP_FIELD, toDate));
```

DateHelper.java

```
public static Date getDateWithoutTime(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTime();
}

public static Date getTomorrowDate(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

And of course - there is always space for refactoring in every code.

Answer (score 4):

The like operator can only be used on String values. It doesn't make sense on a date.

If you have the date `2011-12-01` (assuming `yyyy-MM-dd` here), and you want all the rows which have their timestamp in this day, then you're searching for all the rows where the timestamp is `>= 2011-12-01` and `< 2011-12-02`.

So, add 1 day to your date (using a temporary Calendar object), and use the following code:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge(TIMESTAMP_FIELD, javaUtilDate));
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt(TIMESTAMP_FIELD, javaUtilDatePlusOneDay));
```

Comment: if i convert date to string then it shows me 2011-12-11 02:00:00' and if i subtract or add one day then my query wont pull plausible results. in this way i will get entries those lies before specified day because of time part.

Comment: Use the appropriate date limits. Set all the time fields (hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds) to 0. That makes the lower bound. Add one day. That makes the upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (model.getFromDOE() != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("createdDate",
                getFormattedFromDateTime(model.getFromDOE())));
    }

    if (model.getToDOE() != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.le("createdDate",
                getFormattedToDateTime(model.getToDOE())));
    }

private Date getFormattedFromDateTime(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTime();
}

private Date getFormattedToDateTime(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```