# Hibernate Query-by-Example with Date

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am using Hibernate's `Example` class to query for objects which do not match the example. Everything works fine so long as I do not have dates in my Hibernate type. However, when I have dates in my Hibernate type, the `Example` never matches. (Since it is a not, I always receive objects which should not be present in the query.)

This is the code I am executing

```
Criteria criteria = databaseSession.createCriteria("Person");
criteria.add(Restrictions.not(Example.create(sqlEntity).excludeNone()));
List entities = criteria.list();
// entities contains more objects than it should
```

If I comment the date property out of my hbm.xml file the query works as expected.

```
<class entity-name="Person">
    ...
    <!-- This property is causing the Example to not match. -->
    <property name="date" type="date">
        <column name="Date"/>
    </property>
</class>
```

The `sqlEntity` object has a date-precision (i.e. the time value is 00:00:00). This is all that is provided into the `sqlEntity` object. That is also why the date property has a type of date rather than timestamp. The actual rows in the SQL table have millisecond precision and times which are not equal to 00:00:00.

How can I perform this Example query with a date precision on a datetime column with millisecond precision?

By the way, I debugged the date value of the `sqlEntity` and the objects from `entities` which should not have been present because of dates. Calling `Object.equals()` on those two objects returns `true`.

Comment: Why use a Date without time to map a column containing a date with time?

Comment: "The sqlEntity object has a date-precision (i.e. the time value is 00:00:00). This is all that is provided into the sqlEntity object. That is also why the date property has a type of date rather than timestamp.", it is quite wrong, they both save time, the only difference between Timestamp and Date is nanoseconds which Timestamp has.

Comment: @JBNizet - The input to `sqlEntity` does not have the full date and time. Also, my Hibernate objects which come from the database only need the date portion. Some clients of the database may need the time.

Comment: I hope that the entity is read-only. Else you'll delete the time portion of the date every time you update such an entity. An Example query is not the right tool for this job. Exclude the date property from the example, and use a regular restriction for the date property.

Comment: @JMelnik - The objects store the time, but the values are 00:00:00. I understand that this is not an unknown precision. As I mentioned at the end, `Object.equals()` does return true for the two dates. So, at least when returning, Hibernate does set the time portion to 00:00:00.

Comment: @JBNizet - yes, the entity is read-only. I will try removing the property from the `Example` object and adding it as a restriction on the criteria.

Comment: You are asking "How can I perform query on entity with a date precision on a datetime column with millisecond precision?", maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8970260/685962) what you are looking for?

Comment: A general note: be careful with `java.util.Date` properties and Hibernate. Hibernate returns a `java.sql.Timestamp` for these properties, and **equals** for `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` is **not symetric**.