# How to pick a record by using only date in a timestamp field?

Tags: sql, jpa, hsqldb

I am creating an application using HSQL. Now I need to fetch all the records using some particular date - `yyyy-MM-dd`, but the column is a timestamp date-type - `yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss.ffffff`.

How would I write a HSQL / JPA query to pick all the records using a given date from the table using the timestamp field?

I am new to HSQL & JPA. I have no clue.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8970260/685962

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HSQLDB 2.2.8, use `WHERE datetime_column >= the_date AND datetime_column < the_date + 1` in the JPQL query so that an index on the datetime_column is used for the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table 
where cast(datetime_column as date) = '2012-04-14'
```