# How to write JPA Query to the equivalent mysql query

Tags: jpa

I want to write equivalent JPA query to the following mysql query

```
select active_package,sum(duration),sum(charge),count(*) 
  from User 
  where call_type="MO" 
        and start_date between '2012-02-01' and '2012-02-09' 
  group by active_package;
```

For JPA Query the corresponding  Attributes are below.

activePackage,callType,duration,charge,startDate

Entity class is User.

I want to use the createQuery() of JPA.

Can any one tell me or give me the link where can i find the solution for this.

Comment: hello can any one give me the reply.......

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, it should work, if not, please comment, we will get it work :).

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = cb.createQuery(Tuple.class);

Root<User> entity = cq.from(User.class);
cq.multiselect(entity.get("activePackage"),
        cb.sum(entity.get("duration").as(Long.class)),
        cb.sum(entity.get("charge").as(Double.class),
        cb.count(entity).as(Long.class)));
cq.where(cb.equal(entity.get("callType"), "MO"),
        cb.between(entity.get("startDate").as(Date.class),
        new Date(), new Date()));
cq.groupBy(entity.get("activePackage"));

List<Tuple> resultList = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    for (Tuple result : resultList) {
        System.out.println(result.get(0) + " " + result.get(1)
                + " " + result.get(2) + " " + result.get(3));
}
```

Also if you want to filter only by date, but have timestamp in your model, you can check this [Compare date's date part only with Timestamp in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969943/compare-dates-date-part-only-with-timestamp-in-hibernate/8970260) answer.

Also JPA provides constructing result classes as return values, so you can group your columns. [Read more.](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#Result_Classes_Constructor_Expressions_)

Comment: I am using the jpa query as follows but i am getting the java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return Exception.The query looks like below TypedQuery<RaBdrRating> uQuery = (TypedQuery<RaBdrRating>) entityManager.createQuery("SELECT activePackage,SUM(duration),SUM(charge),COUNT(activePackage) FROM RaBdrRating WHERE callType = :callType and startDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate GROUP BY activePackage",RaBdrRating.class);
       List<RaBdrRating> listOfPackages = uQuery.getResultList();
      
       return listOfPackages;

Comment: Yes i tried that one also it is also giving the exception.But my requirement is i have to use only TypedQuery.

Comment: Can you check the query you have given once.Because it is telling that expecting close found precision.I checked it but i didnt find anything wrong.So can you please check it once.

Comment: I don't know types for every field in your JPA model, so you should check types. In `entity.get("duration").as(Long.class)` duration is Long, apply your's type. In `cb.sum(entity.get("charge").as(Double.class)` charge is Double, appy your's type.