# openJPA date format

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, openjpa

I created entity from the tables . Here is my employee entity.

Class Emp{ 
  String id, 
  java.sql.date joinDate 
}

As i see to_date() is not applicable in JPA,  How can i persist the joined date in the same format 2010-12-25T12:00:00 into the database by using jpa.

How can i specify this format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.

Later on i want to search the emp who has joined in the format (yyyy-mm-dd) 2010-12-25, so that i can get all the values from the database 
2010-12-25T12:00:00 
2010-12-25T11:00:00 
2010-12-25T10:05:00

@NamedQuery(name="getEmployeeByDate",query="select p from Emp p where p.joinDate =? ")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't save the date value "2010-12-25T12:00:00" directly in the database.So we have to convert that to the date time using SimpleDateFormat's parse method.with the help of parse method you can get the date time value.Then you can store that value into the column which has the type as TimeStamp.

For Retrieval the value,get the values as the dateTime,then format the value using the simpledatformat class's format method in java.text package.

Comment: Even i use SimpleDateFormat or whatever, the openJPA show in same format such as "Fri Jul 06 00:00:00 EDT 2012". I just want to have "Jul-06-2012"(no time). Is there a parameter in persistence.xml which does that?

Answer (score 1):

## Analysis

You are mixing the way data is stored and the way data is previewed. Database does not care about formatting, user does.

Store dates in database using [TemporalType](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/types#Date_and_Time_Temporal_Types_), there are three forms: date, time and timestamp.

Preview dates to user using [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html): yyyy-MM-dd, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, etc.

Query database by any parts of your given date (ignoring the format) by [removing unnecessary parts of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969943/compare-dates-date-part-only-with-timestamp-in-hibernate/8970260#8970260).

## Solution

You need two dates, one will represent today at 00:00 and tomorrow at 00:00, which will cover 24hours day. Remove time from both dates and pass them to query:

```
Date fromTimestamp = new Date();
Date toTimestamp = new Date();
Date fromDate = DateHelper.getDateWithoutTime(fromTimestamp);
Date toDate = DateHelper.getDateWithoutTime(
                    DateHelper.getTomorrowDate(toTimestamp));

//DateHelper.java
public static Date getDateWithoutTime(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTime();
}

public static Date getTomorrowDate(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

Update your query to use two parameters:

```
@NamedQuery(name="getEmployeeByDate",
    query="select p from Emp p where p.joinDate >= ? and p.joinDate <= ?")
```

Answer (score 0):

To save the date directly in the database JAVA6 introduce TimeStamp class ([java.sql.Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)).

Firstly replace your entity with

> Class Emp{ String id, TimeStamp joinDate }

Now you can set the joinDate with your desired format using setdate(), setHour()... method to specify your time, that will be directly accepted by SQL TIMESTAMP.