# grails or hibernate criteria to search only by time component

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

Given below is my Domain object.

```
Game {
    Date startDate
}
```

Now I want to only search the games which start at hh:mm AM (dynamic search) in the morning regardless of date. I am looking for Grails criteria something like this

```
Game.where {
    startDate.timePart == timeValue
}.list()
```

Where timeValue  = "10:30 AM" or anything like that.

I am using Hibernate criteria due to some custom restrictions that aren't support in GORM, so it would be nice if anyone knows how to do it with Hibernate criteria.

Right now this is what I am trying to do in Hibernate Criteria and it doesn't work(I am using postgre).

```
searchCriteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("to_timestamp(start_date, 'h:mm a') = ? ", timeValue, StandardBasicTypes.DATE))
```

Highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HibernateCriteriaBuilder.
The builder can be retrieved through the "createCriteria()" dynamic static method of Grails domain classes:

```
   def c = Game.createCriteria()
   def results = c {
     eq("start_date",timeValue)
   }
```

The builder can also be instantiated standalone with a SessionFactory and persistent Class instance:

```
  new HibernateCriteriaBuilder(clazz, sessionFactory).list {
     eq("start_date", timeValue)
  }
```

Comment: @Fahimah - Thanks a lot for your response. If I try to use the implementation by you then grails criteria will try to match "start_date" as a date. What I want is, to compare only the time component. From GUI, user will enter something like 10:30 AM, and I will have to list all the Games start at this time irrespective of date.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a Date instance with only time and use that in Hibernate Criteria API to query.

[Compare date's date part only with Timestamp in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969943/compare-dates-date-part-only-with-timestamp-in-hibernate?lq=1)

Comment: If I create Date instance only with time still it won't work as "startDate" is a timestamp saved in database and comparing it only with time won't return the expected results.